# sql command to get date range data

Tags: mysql, sql

i am working on a car booking system and need help regarding the search for date ranges in mysql

i have a table bookings with 2 date fields (start_date,end_date)

When i want to search for the cars that are available on a date range i have trouble to write the sql command because are involved 2 date ranges
One i give to find which cars are availables in that date range
and second the date range that are in the booking table (start_date,end_date)

The problem that there are at least 4 different things to consider because at the given date range i have to show all the cars and for each day if the car is available or not.

Here is an example

Consider i want to search which cars are available between 30 April 2018 and 03 May 2018

- I have to get the booked cars that have start_date before 30 April 2018 and end_date <= 03 May 2018
- I have to get the booked cars that have start_date before 30 April 2018 and end_date > 03 May 2018
- I have to get the booked cars that have start_date after 30 April 2018 and end_date >= 03 May 2018
- I have to get the booked cars that have start_date and  end_date between the given dates (which is the easy one)

Comment: sounds like a series of OR clauses in your WHERE. Have you tried anything? Also have you considered cars which are not in the bookings table at all? If they've never been booked, they could still be available. You haven't made the data structure fully clear, but it seems to me this could be a possibility.

Comment: When you say 'MySQL command' what you really mean is 'SQL query'. Be precise.

Comment: @ADyson yes i have consider the cars that are not booked, thanks for your mention, and yes it sounds like series of OR clauses but there are some points that are a little bit odd because the agent can select a date range of a single day ex show me the bookings for April 30 and i have to draw that he has to deliver the car 1 and pickup the car2 and there are car3 and car4 that is already delivered and has nothing to do (this is the agent diary)

Comment: @EJP yes you are correct

Comment: @ntan I'm not sure what the last part has to do with this query really. That sounds more like how you interpret your data (and possibly some other data is needed too, I don't know for sure, it's too vague). And a date range of 1 day can be treated exactly the same way as a date range of 1000 days.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looking forward to fetch multiple records in a transaction, i would recommend writing  a **stored procedure** (Present in MS sql- should be the same with MySql) with a **Union condition** for each statement.

Which will allow you to control the list of all queries data to be complied and returned as a single result set.